# How can I resize an one-hot-encoded image (Ground-truth) for training a semantic image segmentation model?

Tags: numpy, opencv, pytorch, semantic-segmentation

I am trying to train a model for semantic image segmentation task. I have 3 classes meaning that, for one sample, the ground-truth will have the shape (3, 512, 512).
This shape (3, 512, 512) is interpreted in the next way:

- first channel (1, 512, 512) corresponds to background class having 1's where the pixels correspond to that class, 0 otherwise;
- (2, 512, 512) corresponds to the 2nd class having again 1's where the pixels corresponds to that class, 0's otherwise;
- similar for the 3rd class.

My problem is: 512x512 is a high resolution array and I want to save my VRAM memory and also speedup the train process. I want to find a way to downsample this one-hot-encoded array by 2 (having 256x256 resolution).
How can I achive that having just 1's and 0's in the resulted array? ( I tried it using the resize function from opencv but it yields values which are different from 0 and 1)
What techniques for interpolation are used for this situation? A solution in opencv/numpy/pytorch/other libraries is welcomed.

Comment: You could encode the labels as a single channel image of indices corresponding to the class label and then resize with nearest neighbor interpolation.

Answer (score 0):

##### Changing encoding

As [@jodag](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2790047/jodag) pointed out, you can convert you can go from one-hot encoding to dense encoding. This means you only store a class index on a single channel and the representation in memory is no longer sparse.

You can easily achieve this by calling [`torch.Tensor.argmax`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.argmax.html). For a given tensor `x` shaped `(3, 512, 512)`, you can do:

```
>>> d = x.argmin(dim=0)
```

And still, you are able to go back to one-hot encoding using [`tf.one_hot`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.functional.one_hot.html), PyTorch's one-hot encoding utility function:

```
>>> x = tf.one_hot(d, num_classes=3).permute(2,0,1)
```

This will result in a tensor of shape `(3, 512, 512)` as you described.

***There is no loss of information involved with this method.***

---

##### Resizing with correct mode

When resizing your input array, you probably did not change the interpolation mode which meant that there was some kind of interpolation in the resulting tensor which led to non `{0, 1}` values. Use the nearest neighbor mode to retain the same values:

```
resize(x, size=(256, 256), interpolation=InterpolationMode.NEAREST)
```

Where `InterpolationMode` is an `enum` from [`torchvision.transforms`](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/main/torchvision/transforms/functional.py#L21-L34) and [`resize`](https://pytorch.org/vision/main/generated/torchvision.transforms.functional.resize.html?highlight=resize#torchvision.transforms.functional.resize) is imported from [`torchvision.transforms.functional`](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/main/torchvision/transforms/functional.py).

***There is a loss of information involved with this method.***